# Problema a aceder a base de dados de SQL sem erro

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho um código que usa SQL , e nessa base de dados , tenho uma coluna de datas, depois tenho um código que o que faz é retornar o maxID(numero de rows, ou seja numero de datas) e tenho outro código que vai a essa coluna e retorna a data com o ID especificado no parâmetro.Para isto "funcionar " tenho um método que o que faz é fazer um loop pelo método que retorna a data com o ID especificado no parâmetro , e depois com essa data usa um método do Caldroid , setBackgroundDrawable.

Bem o problema é que não esta a funcionar mas também não tem erro.

Código dos metodos que retornam o maxID e a data de ID(x):

```
      public int getLastId() {
    String query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    int id = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            id = cursor.getInt(0);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    return id;

}

public String getDates(int numero){
    String date = "";
    String last_query = "SELECT " + COL_4  + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME  + " WHERE " + COL_1 + " = '" + numero + "'";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(last_query, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    {
        date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DIA")); // Return Value
    }
    c.close();
    return date;
}
```

}

metodo que chama esses dois métodos com um loop:

```
      public void addToCalendar(){

    myDB = CustomApplication.getDatabaseHelper();
    ColorDrawable blue = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE);
    for(int i=0;i == myDB.getLastId();i++){
        String dt = myDB.getDates(i);
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date teste = null;
        try {
            teste = sdf.parse(dt);
            caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(blue,teste);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```